# 'java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl,'

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, adal4j, azure-sql

I am using below dependencies.

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
             <version>7.4.1.jre8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>adal4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

When I form the connection url like below.

```
  String connectionUrl = jdbcURL + ";databaseName=" + databaseName + ";user=" + userName + ";password="
                    + password
                    + ";encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;"
                    + "loginTimeout=30;authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword";
```

I am getting error like:

> ' **'java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl,**'

When I enclosed the password in curly braces like below, I am able to successfully connect to Azure sql server.

```
String connectionUrl = jdbcURL + ";databaseName=" + databaseName + ";user=" + userName + ";password={"
                + password + "}"
                + ";encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;"
                + "loginTimeout=30;authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword";
```

Just FYI, password has one open curly brace {, is it causing any trouble? is it mandatory to enclose the password string in curly braces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is resolved when I set the password using setPassword method.

```
dataSource.setPassword(password);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to update the db.url
from this:

```
jdbc:sqlserver:myservername.awsaddress.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1433;databaseName=exdb
```

to this:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://myservername.awsaddress.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1433;databaseName=exdb
```

I forgot the double forward slash.